# In Scala how to make a thread wait for a future results to be ready?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

I have a callback handler which handles one of many phases of a URL processing. In this handler I have to use a third party library (scala interface)and compute some value which will set one global configuration. This configuration is used by followings phase and value it gets in callback handler plays a critical role.

Here is how design looks

```
def callbackHandler() : someReturnType = {
    val myFut = getMyData() // return a future
    myFut map {m => set_global} // evaluate the future
    someReturnTypeObject
}
```

With this context, here is my question. Scala API I am using returns a future to me, and I evaluate it using "map". As I understand after getting future instance, callback function will move on with pending stuff and future will be evaluated when it is available(in a separate thread).

In such scenario how I will make sure to keep callback handler waiting for future evaluation?

moving line 4 to map body may not work, as callbackhandler may still return early if map is taking time.Please let me know if you have some question, or if I am wrong in my understanding.

Comment: As commented below, while you can block you really shouldn't and your question may be better rephrased as how you should design your system as not require blocking on a future

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using a `Future` is to not block a thread. Ideally you should execute the code you want as part of the completion of the future, rather than blocking the future and resume on the same thread.

That said, the mechanism for blocking on a future is:

```
val result = Await.result(myFut, 10.seconds)
```

where `10.seconds` is the longest you are willing to wait.

You should also note that `map` does not *evaluate* the future. The evaluation starts as soon as you call `getMyData`. All that `map` does is transform the result of the future into a future, once that result is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... in this scenario only thing in my control is what I write in the handler. These phases and scala interface is pre existing and being used for quite some time. I cant really change them, or go to other alternatives.
On "rather than blocking the future and resume on the same thread", how I can do that without keeping callback handler in wait? I mean moment it exits I loose control over the pase, so I have to keep it with me and process the future.
Please let me know If I am getting it right or not.

Comment: Without seeing more of the consuming system it's hard to tell how you can avoid blocking, and it is true that once you go async, it's usually an *async all the way down* scenario. I.e. anything that calls something that returns a future, really needs to return a future itself and so on. This is why more an more web frameworks support asynchronous request handlers, so that the response can be provided via the onComplete of a future rather than having to block the request thread.

Comment: Thanks for your advise,I understand the idea better now, and will try to make modification accordingly.